# DKIM is not Failing When Messages Come From Another Domain

Tags: linux, email, dkim

Somebody sent out spam messages with a forged `From:` address, so that the messages appeared to come from us. The headers clearly show otherwise. We have DKIM and SPF set up. The problem is that in the bounce messages that came to us, I noticed this line:

```
Authentication-Results: mta1097.sbc.mail.bf1.yahoo.com  from=mydomain.org; domainkeys=neutral (no sig);  from=mydomain.org; dkim=neutral (no sig)
```

I believe that this should say `dkim=fail`, which should cause all such messages to bounce. Instead, many were delivered. If it's relevant, when we do send messages through our server, DKIM passes. Is there a setting that can be changed in OpenDKIM to fix this?

Comment: How exactly you have configured DKIM? One part is located in the DNS zone config and the other in the mailer config. Please do not show your key from mailer config.

Comment: The DNS shows:

`mail._domainkey.healthwyze.org IN      TXT ("v=DKIM1; k=rsa; " "p=KEY_REMOVED_FOR_BREVITY")`

I'm not sure which part of the postfix/opendkim configuration you are requesting. However, it appears to be signing e-mails correctly, since mails do "pass".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define policies how other mail servers should handle receiving mail regarding SPF and DKIM fails, use [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC). If no DMARC policy is defined other postmaster can defined their own rules how to handle DKIM fails.

Use this policy to reject all mails:

```
_dmarc.example.com    TXT    v=DMARC1; p=reject;
```